# How to change order of User Profile properties on user's MySite

Tags: my-site, user-profile-property, ordering

I want to change the order of properties on user's Mysite, How i do that? In the below picture, I want to move up "Mobile Phone" property under "Phone" property. [image]

And secondly how i get to know the order of each profile property ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, based on what Mike [claims here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3dc4bc1a-0a34-4fbc-b290-05425c7987d9/change-the-order-of-user-properties-on-mysite?forum=sharepointadminprevious) the ordering is controlled by the order the rendering controls for the properties are added on the page. For some pages this could be modified using SharePoint designer, but for others this is not possible.

That means that as far as I know, custom ordering should not be supported.

Also worth mentioning [this article](http://www.sharepointfire.com/MyBlog/2014/02/moving-user-properties-up-in-sharepoint-with-powershell/), that illustrate a possible workaround. I don't have yet tested it so I don't know if it works. Since the original post date a year passed, so maybe now there is some official info from Microsoft. I will update as soon as I find something about this.

Comment: Thanks, I have already used Powershell command to re-order the properties. When i look into Order of properties. "Phone" property have order no 11 and "Mobile Phone" property was at no 5103. Then I Change the order of "Mobile Phone" property using powershell and give it new order no 12. But when i see and refresh the profile page. It still shows me in the old order. I am not sure if i did correct, let me know if i did wrong?

Comment: This is wrong. You can reorder user profile properties at will using eg. `SetDisplayOrderByPropertyName` via PowerShell as explained here: https://www.quanta.co.uk/blog/2015/09/sharepoint-2013-changing-order-user-profile-properties the MSDN article is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.profilesubtypepropertymanager.setdisplayorderbyname(v=office.14).aspx

After reordering you will need to run at least an Incremental sync for the ordering to show up on the profile info page.